# Add the symbol take care

Tags: bclogo

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}   % it load graphicx too
\usepackage{fancybox}       % pour faire l'encadrement

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}

%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\vspace{-1em}
\vspace{0.0cm}
        \begin{center}
            \shadowbox{
                \fbox{ \parbox{.85\linewidth}{ \centering\textbf{\textsf{\large{{\huge{E}}xamen Final en Mathématiques {\huge{I}}} (Session principale) } } \par
                \textbf{08 Junvier 2022} ( 11h.00 \ding{217} 12h.30 )
    }}
    }
\end{center}
%-------attention----- Une présentation générale soignée sera appréciée.
\vspace{-0.4cm}
\begin{center}
\emph{\texttt{\textbf{Aucun document n'est autorisé. Seules les calculatrices non-programmables et non graphiques sont autorisées. Il sera tenu compte de la rigueur et de la clarté de la rédaction. Cet énoncé comporte $4$ exercices indépendants.}}}
\end{center}
%-------------- FIN DE L'ENTETE----------------------
\end{document}
```

I want to add the symbole take care

[image]

Like the following

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bclogo` package uses an environment:

```
\begin{bclogo}[options]{title}
contents
\end{bclogo}
```

The options allow you to specify the logo and the border, among other things. The caution ('take care') sign is called `\bcattention` (see the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/bclogo/doc/bclogo-doc.pdf) for the full list of available logos). The border can be switched off using `noborder=true`. The title can be left empty.

In the MWE below I also added an alternative package for this kind of logos, `awesomebox` (which uses logos from the FontAwesome5 font). I also changed the month name. Finally I removed the `inputenc` and `fontenc` packages as they are not really needed here.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}   % it load graphicx too
\usepackage{fancybox}       % pour faire l'encadrement

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}

\usepackage{awesomebox}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\vspace{-1em}
\vspace{0.0cm}
        \begin{center}
            \shadowbox{
                \fbox{ \parbox{.85\linewidth}{ \centering\textbf{\textsf{\large{{\huge{E}}xamen Final en Mathématiques {\huge{I}}} (Session principale) } } \par
                \textbf{08 Janvier 2022} ( 11h.00 \ding{217} 12h.30 )
    }}
    }
\end{center}
%-------attention----- Une présentation générale soignée sera appréciée.
\vspace{-0.4cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{bclogo}[logo=\bcattention,noborder=true]{}
Aucun document n'est autorisé. Seules les calculatrices non-programmables et non graphiques sont autorisées. Il sera tenu compte de la rigueur et de la clarté de la rédaction. Cet énoncé comporte $4$ exercices indépendants.
\end{bclogo}
\definecolor{abwarning}{RGB}{188,0,0}
\warningbox{Aucun document n'est autorisé. Seules les calculatrices non-programmables et non graphiques sont autorisées. Il sera tenu compte de la rigueur et de la clarté de la rédaction. Cet énoncé comporte $4$ exercices indépendants.}
\end{center}
%-------------- FIN DE L'ENTETE----------------------
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]